# mysql query to find the longest run in a column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in a mysql table that lists winners from a game.
I'm trying to find a query that will return the longest run of wins for each player.
Or a way to interpret a query with php.

In this case it would be 
Kate 4,
Ed 1,
Mike 2,
Harry 1,

```
**Winner**
Kate
Kate
Ed
Harry
Ed
Harry
Mike
Mike
Ed
Harry
Kate    
Kate  
Kate
Kate
Ed
```

Apologies in advance as I am very new to all of this.

Comment: in php it's simple. select the winners, fetch the rows, and keep a running count as you loop. in sql, it's a lot uglier.

Comment: do you have an ID or a timestamp in your table? how can you order rows?

Comment: You need a Primary Key. After that, it's a doddle.

Comment: I have both ID and DateTime in my table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT winner, MAX(winningStreak) FROM (
SELECT
winner,
IF(winner=@prev, @rownum:=@rownum+1, @rownum:=1) AS winningStreak,
@prev:=winner
FROM
yourTable
, (SELECT @prev:=NULL, @rownum:=1) vars
/*ORDER BY whateverDeterminesTheOrderOfTheWinners*/
)sq
GROUP BY winner
ORDER BY winningStreak DESC
```

You need another column which determines the order of the winners like you have listed them and adjust the outcommented part of the query. Apart from that this query works, but it would really be easier done in PHP.

See it live [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4257d/4).

Comment: Cool. I never knew an sqlfiddle existed!

Comment: Nice. I bet this query scales well too.

Answer (score 2):

Using variables would make the query more simple, but I wanted to solve it using just SQL. This is my query:

```
SELECT winner, COALESCE(MAX(id2-min_id1), 0)+1
FROM (
  SELECT MIN(w1.id) min_id1, w1.winner, w2.id id2
  FROM
    winners w1 LEFT JOIN winners w2
    ON w1.id < w2.id
       AND w1.winner = w2.winner
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM winners w3
                WHERE w3.winner != w1.winner
                      AND w3.id > w1.id AND w3.id < w2.id)
  GROUP BY
    w2.id, w1.winner
  ) s
GROUP BY
  winner
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3a02/1). I'm using an ID because without an ID or a timestamp, order of rows returned by a SQL query cannot be determined. This assumes that ID has no gaps.

Answer (score 1):

OK, my turn... this assumes that id is auto_incrementing with no gaps...

```
SELECT winner
     , MAX(streak) longest_streak
  FROM
     ( SELECT a.*
            , MIN( c.id ) - a.id + 1 streak
         FROM results a
         LEFT 
         JOIN results b 
           ON a.id = b.id + 1 
          AND b.winner = a.winner
         LEFT 
         JOIN results c 
           ON a.id <= c.id 
          AND c.winner = a.winner
         LEFT 
         JOIN results d 
           ON c.id = d.id - 1 
          AND d.winner = a.winner
        WHERE b.id IS NULL
          AND c.id IS NOT NULL
          AND d.id IS NULL
        GROUP 
           BY a.id
     ) x
 GROUP
    BY winner
 ORDER  
    BY longest_streak DESC;
```