# Sequence of x values on database

Tags: mysql, sql

Example: I have 200 results from my query.

```
Result
----------    
true
false
false
true
true
true
false
false
.
.
.
```

Can i know if there is a sequence of x "true" in my result, using mysql?

Example: I want to know if in this result i have a sequence of 20 "true", non-stop, without a single false between this 20 "true".

Thanks!

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do you have another column that controls the order?  Can you query also return some `id` field that can be used for sorting?

Comment: Fresh, im really sorry if you are offended to my question. Im asking here because i don't even know how to search this on google. I don't know if there's a name of this that i want.

PM, i can do this, but it will not be sequential.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql query to find the longest run in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815031/mysql-query-to-find-the-longest-run-in-a-column)

Comment: @Hor searching here on SO is also a good idea.

Comment: @Hor - I posted an answer below.  If it does not do exactly what you need it should be a good start for you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are my two assumptions:

1. `result` is a `varchar`
2. the query also returns `id` that will be used to set the order so we have a definite sequence (if your original query already applied the consistent order, then you may not need to order the outer query).

The following code will calculate the **maximum** of "true" in an uninterrupted sequence in `Table1` (you will need to apply it to your sub-query):

```
SET @n = 0;
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN result = 'true' THEN @n:=@n+1 ELSE @n:=0 END ) AS "Maximum Number of True"
FROM Table1
ORDER BY id;
```

So you will be whether maximum returned is **at least 20** ( in your case ).

Here's [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36503/7) that you can experiment with.

Comment: This is exactly what im looking for! I tested with my query and it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Hor - You're welcome. MySQL's **in-line assignment** feature is very powerful and allows to write a single query where otherwise you would've needed a procedure with a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the SQL data:

```
create table results
(
  result bool not null
);

insert into results values (1);
insert into results values (0);
insert into results values (0);
insert into results values (1);
insert into results values (1);
insert into results values (1);
insert into results values (0);
insert into results values (0);
```

Here's the query:

```
SELECT result, MAX(streak)
FROM (
      SELECT result,
             IF(result=@prev, @rownum:=@rownum+1, @rownum:=1) AS streak, @prev:=result
      FROM results,
           (SELECT @prev:=NULL, @rownum:=1) vars
     ) sq
GROUP BY result
ORDER BY streak DESC
```

The result is this:

```
1   3
0   2
```

This tells you that for a `1 = true` value you have a sequence of 3 consecutive 1s and that for a `0 = false` value you have a sequence of 2 consecutive 0s.

The SQL Fiddle to play with the data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f706/12